# Как добавить новый столбец с категорией как результат группировки предыдущих?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, анализ-данных

Есть DataFrame со столбцами 'floor' и 'floors_total'. Мне нужно добавить отдельный столбец с их группировкой: 'Первый', 'Последний' и 'Другой' этажи.

```
def floors_level(floor):
    for row in data['floors_total']:
        if floor == 1:
            return 'Первый'
        if floor == row and floor != 1:
            return 'Последний'
        return 'Другой'
        
        
data['floor_level'] = data['floor'].apply(floors_level)
```

Функция, которую я пробовал написать, не перебирает все значения столбца 'floors_total' как row, а останавливается на первом, подходящем под условие. С категорией 'Первый' все работает, а с остальными не получается - из 3331 строки, где 'floor' равняется 'floors_total', категории 'Последний' только 308 значений, да и те в большинстве случаев не верные (не подходят под условие `'floor' == 'floors_total'`).

Можете подсказать что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше воспользоваться векторизированным решением, использующим функцию [np.where()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np

def floor_cat(floor, floors_total):
    return np.where(floor==floors_total, "Последний", np.where(floor==1, "Первый", "Другой"))
```

Пример работы:

```
In [220]: df
Out[220]:
   floor  floors_total
0      1             9
1      2             9
2      3             9
3      9             9
4      1            12
5      5            12
6     12            12

In [221]: df["floor_cat"] = floor_cat(df["floor"], df["floors_total"])

In [222]: df
Out[222]:
   floor  floors_total  floor_cat
0      1             9     Первый
1      2             9     Другой
2      3             9     Другой
3      9             9  Последний
4      1            12     Первый
5      5            12     Другой
6     12            12  Последний
```

Comment: Отличный вариант! А можете подсказать мне мою ошибку в функции?

Comment: @Denis, ответил [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1166242/211923)

Answer (score 2):

В вашей реализации существует логическая ошибка и она в том, что вы сравниваете скалярное значение `floor` с вектором значений `data['floors_total']` в цикле.

Для справки

> метод [Series.apply(func)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) передает в функцию `func` значения
> последовательно в виде скаляров / элементов `Series`

Если вызвать `floors_level(12)` для фрейма из моего соседнего ответа, то результатом будет `"Другой"`, вместо ожидаемого `"Последний"`.

```
In [245]: floors_level(12)
Out[245]: 'Другой'
```

Причиной тому логика цикла, которая **всегда** возвращает значение на **первой** итерации и соответственно сравнивает `floor` только со значением `floors_total` из **первой строки**

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь будем знать

Answer (score 0):

Добил функцию без использования numpy.

```
def floors_level(row):
        if row['floor'] == 1:
            return 'Первый'
        if row['floor'] == row['floors_total']:
            return 'Последний'
        return 'Другой'
               
data['floor_level'] = data.apply(floors_level, axis = 1)
```